# Find a minimal set whose elements determine explicitly all integer solutions to $x + y + z = 2n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, integer-partitions, set-partition

Is there a way to exactly parameterise all the solutions to the equation $x + y + z = 2n$, for $z$ less than or equal to $y$, less than or equal to $x$, for positive integers $x,y,z$?

For example, for $n=4$ it is not hard to find explicitly the solutions: $(6,1,1), (5,2,1), (4,3,1), (4,2,2), (3,3,2)$. It seems like a promising strategy is to increment down $x= 2n -2$ in steps of $1$, but as n gets large, this seems like a daunting branching task.

I am aware that the number of solutions is the closest integer to $n^{2}/3$, but I am looking for a sequence that explicitly generates all of these triplets. Moreover, I want this sequence to be 'minimal', i.e. to contain no repeats: is this problem solvable?

I have a way to enumerate these triplets by considering $(2n-2i+2,i+j-1,i-j+1)$ and letting j vary from 1 to i and i vary from 1 to n, however, these produce many repetitions (which makes sense, as we have $n(n+1)/2$ elements as opposed to the nearest integer to $n^{2}/3$).

It is not good enough for me to simply delete the repetitions- I need the number of elements in this generating sequence to be precisely equal to the number of distinct solutions- so the minimal set of solutions.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492661/generating-all-integer-solutions-to-x-y-z-2n-not-number-of-solutions) repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that for $n=1$ you have that $x+y+z>2$ and thus that there are no solutions. So assume $n>1$.

Just fix $x$ to be the smallest positive integer $1$. Notice that $z=2n-x-y$ and thus you can let $y=1$ and see if it fits, then $y=2$, etc. until you cannot satisfy $z\geq y\geq x>0$ anymore. If you had all triples with $x=1$, then move to $x=2$ and do the same procedure again. And so on, until $x$ becomes too large to even find a value for $y$ and then the procedure stops.

Above gives an algorithm to find all triples satisfying $x+y+z=2n$.

Comment: This indeed enumerates all solutions algorithimically and without repetition- however, I am looking for a sequence of length $n^2/3$ whose elements are triplets, which precisely determine the solution (for example for the case of pairs x + y = n this is done by the answer below)

Comment: @Noam Both answers are the same: loop over x, then loop over y. You get a sequence by just putting the solutions in a sequence.

Comment: But the method below does yield repetitions- for n=8 you have x=4=y' giving y=1, z=3 but also x=3, y'=5, giving y=1, z=4 (so that 1,3,4 appears twice)

Answer (score 1):

For any $x,n\in \mathbb N$, let $A(x,n)$ denote the list of valid triples summing to $2n$ whose first coordinate is $x$, sorted in increasing order of their second coordinate. We can give an explicit description for $A(x,n)$:
$$
A(x,n):= 
[(x, y, 2n-x-y) \quad\text{ for }\quad \lceil n-x/2\rceil \le y \le \min(2n-x-1,x)]
$$
For example, take $x=15$ and $n=13$. Since $\lceil 13-15/2\rceil=6$, $y$ will start at $6$, and since $\min(2\cdot 13-15-1,13)=\min(10,13)=10$, $y$ will end at $10$. The result is
$$
A(15,13)=[(15,6,5),(15,7,4),(15,8,3),(15,9,2),(15,10,1)]
$$
Then the following list enumerates all valid triples exactly once:
$$
A(\lceil 2n/3\rceil,n)\oplus A(\lceil 2n/3\rceil + 1,n)\oplus \dots \oplus A(2n-2,n)
$$
That is, we take all of the lists $A(x,n)$ for $x$ between $\lceil 2n/3\rceil$ and $2n-2$, inclusive, and concatenate them altogether.

To see that this works, note that all of the triples within $A(x,n)$ are distinct, since they all have different $y$-coordinates. Furthermore, for any $x\neq x'$, all of the triples in $A(x,n)$ are distinct from all of $A(x',n)$, since the $x$-coordinates differ.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x+y=n$ for $x,y\ge 1$ has the solutions $\{(x,n-x)|x=1,...,n-1\}$. Once you have this, to solve $x+y+z=n$ you solve the pair

$$x+y'=n$$
$$y+z=y'$$

Each solution to the top equation $x,y'$ determines a value for $y'$ in the second. Then using each value obtained for $y'$ gives a separate equation for $y,z$ to be solved. This idea is called recursion.

To get your equation, replace $n$ with $2n$.

Using this idea, the parametrisation becomes

$$(x,y,z)=(x,y,2n-x-y)$$

where you take all integers $x>0$ and $y>0$ satisfying $n-x/2\le y\le x$.

Comment: Thanks-this is a nice idea, but it seems to me it will yield repetitions, for example for n=8 will yield 1 + 3 + 4 in two different ways. I am trying to formulate a sequence of length $^2/3$ whose elements are triplets and which precisely determines all the solutions, in much the same way as the set you constructed for x + y = n.

Comment: If you want to get only solutions in decreasing order $x>y>z$ then only take the solutions $\{(x,n-x)|n>x>n/2\}$ to each equation of the form $x+y=n$

Comment: I want to allow for x greater or equal to y, greater or equal to z: I am trying out your parametric construction above right now to see if it indeed produces all such triplets, whilst not having any redundancies

Comment: Indeed as I want to allow all distinct triplets that add up to 2n the construction above does not quite work, and I've tried relaxing the strict inequalities but this  again produces repetitions

Comment: You're right, my mistake. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generating functions

Let us change the question to an equivalent
$y +(y+a) +(y+a+b) = 3y+2a+b = 2n$ over the integers with $y\geq 1,a,b, \geq 0$

Generating functions of $3y,\; 2a,\; b\;$ are respectively $\frac{x^3}{1-x^3},\;\; \frac{1}{1-x^2},\;\; \frac{1}{1-x}$

Finally, find the coefficient of $x^{2n}\;$ in the expansion of
$\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x}$

---

**ADDED**

For example, for $2n=12$, the coefficient is [seen](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+expansion+of++%5Bx%5E3%2F%281-x%5E3%29%5D%5B1%2F%281-x%5E2%29%5D%5B1%2F%281-x%29%5D) as $12$, and confirmed, viz
$11\small{X},$$\;\;129,\;\;138,\;\;147,\;\;156,\;\;228,\;\;237,\;\;246,\;\;255,\;\;336,\;\;345,\;\;444$

Comment: @Noam: By mistake, (or by habit), I took weakly increasing triplets instead of weakly decreasing ones. Of course, it doesn't matter, really.